# JQuery: show div below pushed button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I show the `div`-element below the pushed button?

html:

```
<button id="one" class="btn">One</button>
<button id="two" class="btn">Two</button>
<button id="three" class="btn">Three</button>
<div id="popup">Message!</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
   const targetBtn = e.target;
  $("#popup").show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow"); //HOW TO SHOW IT BELOW TARGET BUTTON
})
```

Comment: Note that only modern browsers support the _const_ statement.

Comment: check my answer, is this what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your div has an `id` not `class` so you have to use `#` notation for ids:

```
$('.btn').click(function (e) {
   $("#popup").css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': $(this).offset().left,
        'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
   }).show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow");
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j83fY/)

Comment: Doesn't show div below the button. The Distance is pretty big

Comment: thanks! Still doesn't work, but maybe there are problems on my side (css?). So I will fix these problems by my own

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your button is allready visible or not before you want to replace it. But this puts the div after the clicked button:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#popup").insertAfter($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6FLLt/

If you want to `show()` it use

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#popup").show().insertAfter($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6FLLt/2/

UPDATE

If you want to place the message below the buttons visually you have to change to html and CSS like so:

HTML

```
<div class="relative">
    <button id="one" class="btn">One</button>
</div>
<div class="relative">
    <button id="two" class="btn">Two</button>
</div>
<div class="relative">
    <button id="three" class="btn">Three</button>
</div>
<div id="popup">Message!</div>
```

CSS

```
#popup{position:absolute; bottom:-20px; display:none;}
.relative{position:relative; float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6FLLt/5/

Comment: But if I click on the first button, then popup will shift the next two buttons.  Means that `after` is on the `right-hand` instead of `below`

Comment: Ah, I understand you question now I think. I thought you meant below it in code. But you meant optical.
I guess you would have to wrap the button in a `div` with a `position:relative`. Then you can offset the message with negative margin.

See my updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6FLLt/5/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
   $(this).after($('#popup'));
})
```

Note : User `#` for id and `.`(dot) for class

Comment: It works for me, but the same problem that with `insertAfter` (see answer above). So upvote from me. P.S. you maybe mean `.after(e.target)`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show the div-element below the pushed button?

Set the margin of the div accordingly (to show the div directly below the pushed button):

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    var $elem = $(e.target), 
        $div = $('#popup');
    $div.css('margin-left', $elem.offset().left + 'px');
    $("#popup").stop().show("slow").delay(500).hide("slow"); 
})
```

*Demo*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5ef5L/**

*Note*: You should `.stop()` before attempting the animation, because when you click another button, the earlier animation might still be underway, hence giving unexpected results.

*Aside*: You need to use the `$('#...')` selector, because *popup* is an `id`.