# How to show a message status below the rate button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a rate button on my page, created using PHP and jQuery.

When the button is clicked, a message is shown and hidden after a while *"#num voted including you"*

HTML:

```
div class="voting_wrapper" id="1001">
    <div class="voting_btn">
        <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <span class="up_votes"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     //####### on page load, retrive votes for each content
     $.each( $('.voting_wrapper'), function(){
         //retrive unique id from this voting_wrapper element
         var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");
         //prepare post content
         post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};
        //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
         $.post('vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {
                //retrive votes from server, replace each vote count text
                 $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up +' user has voted'); 
             },'json');
     });

     //####### on button click, get user vote and send it to vote_process.php using jQuery $.post().
     $(".voting_wrapper .voting_btn").click(function (e) {

         //get class name (down_button / up_button) of clicked element
         var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');

         //get unique ID from voted parent element
         var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 

         if(clicked_button==='up_button') { //user liked the content
             //prepare post content
             post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};

             //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
             $.post('vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

                 //replace vote up count text with new values
                 $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);
                 //thank user for liking the content
                 dataModified = data+' users has voting including you';
                 $('#message-status').hide().html(dataModified).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
             }).fail(function(err) { 

             //alert user about the HTTP server error
                 alert(err.statusText); 
             });
         }

     });
     //end 

 });
```

It works fine, but placement of the message is incorrect. When I click the button, that message status shows up at the top of the page, while I need it to be shown below the rate button.

May I know how to add the code to achieve this? I think I could use `append();` but I am struggling where and how to add the script. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can use `append()`,.. have you tried it? any problem you faced with `append()`?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111256/jquery-show-div-below-pushed-button

Comment: I m new to jquery, so, i  just confused ,how to add in my existing script?

Comment: please provide full javascript and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is that, is probably because the `#message-status` element is initially placed outside of the `voting_wrapper` element. You could move `#message-status` inside that *wrapper*, below the `.voting_btn` button using [**`.insertAfter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```
$('#message-status').hide().html(dataModified).insertAfter('#'+unique_id+' .voting_btn').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
```

So that after AJAX call, your HTML becomes:

```
<div class="voting_wrapper" id="1001">
    <div class="voting_btn">
        <div class="up_button">&nbsp;ddd</div>
        <span class="up_votes">X</span>
    </div>
    <div id="message-status">X users has voting including you</div>
</div>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you need the message below the whole `voting_wrapper`, use this:

```
$('#message-status').hide().html(dataModified).insertAfter('#'+unique_id).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
```

Comment: Your code working fine, thanks @phillip: and i need to show below the button.. but now it shows, near the button. thanks

Comment: now shows like, xx users voted in near by the rate button and "including you" showed next line.. i need full line displayed below the rate button.. thanks .

Comment: @sona , Then it's most likely related to CSS settings. Difficult to answer because you posted to small part of the HTML and no CSS.

Comment: Thanks @phillip: But if we append means, it will be show below the buton right? .. i know only jquery at basic level only..

Comment: @sona , yes. You need to play with CSS. Look at the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xh99gk36/) . The message is at the top of the page, but when AJAX is complete, message box is moved under the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your code,

```
$('#message-status').hide().html(dataModified).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
```

with this

```
$('#message-status').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': $(this).offset().left,
        'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
   }).hide().html(dataModified).show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow");
```

Comment: @ Nishant Solanki: thanks for spending your time,  i got a solution from phillip's post.